# Check if file exist on SFTP remote server

Tags: c#, sftp, sharpssh

The following code will download the file named `file.txt` from the SFTP remote server to the local machine.

```cs
sftp.Get("/usr/mine/file.txt" , "C:/Folder/");
```

What I want to do is check if the file `file.txt` exist on the remote server or not. How can I do this check?

I am using `SharpSSH`

Comment: You need to request file attributes. You'll get an error if the file doesn't exist.

Comment: You might as well just try to download the file and catch the exception if it doesn't exist.  It's a race condition anyways.

Comment: @BryanCrosby Yes i thought of this way as well. But there might be a better method i guess.

Comment: @Illep: Let's say you check that the file exists, but then something happens between your check (file gets locked, deleted, etc).  You might as well just attempt the download.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your reply. I would mark it as an answer if you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could consider just taking the small hit and attempting to download the file.  If it doesn't exist, an exception should be thrown and you can just catch it and move on.  Checking for a file's existence is a volatile situation so in the majority of cases it's best to try and perform your action.

Comment: Not a good approach. You are wasting too much traffic.

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick.

```cs
using (var sftp = new SftpClient(host, username, password))
{
    try
    {

        sftp.Connect();
        MessageBox.Show(sftp.Exists(remoteDirectory).ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception Sftpex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Sftpex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this by using .GetFileList and reading the values into an ArrayList and then looping thru each value, adding the filename to a list box.  I then check my input file against the list box to see if it exists.  Sample code below to add the .GetFileList values into an ArrayList and then into a list box.

BTW - this is VB.NET :)

```
Dim InputFileList As ArrayList = oSftp.GetFileList(frmOptions.tbFTPInboundFolder.Text)
 For Each f In InputFileList
                If f.ToString() <> "." AndAlso f.ToString <> ".." Then
                    frmMain.lbFTPInputDirectory.Items.Add(f)
                End If
            Next
```